# Deleting empty (zero-byte) files

Tags: command-line, file, batch-file

What's the easiest/best way to find and remove empty (zero-byte) files using only tools native to Mac OS X?

Comment: please clarify! one file that's empty, all empty files? what have you tried, what where the errors?

Comment: A comment to my answer clarified the question; updating appropriately.

Comment: Thank you Charles Duffy. Sorry for my bad English :p

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easy enough:

```
find . -type f -size 0 -exec rm -f '{}' +
```

---

To ignore any file having xattr content (assuming the MacOS `find` implementation):

```
find . -type f -size 0 '!' -xattr -exec rm -f '{}' +
```

That said, note that many xattrs are not particularly useful (for example, `com.apple.quarantine` exists on all downloaded files).

Comment: I use

find . -size 0 -exec rm {} \;

but add -type f should be better

Comment: So, in English, "find all empty files in the current directory and delete them without prompting the user"?

Comment: So how would you do this recursively?

Comment: @endolith - the command already given does recurse; you'd need to use an argument such as `-maxdepth 1` to prevent it from doing so.

Comment: @Bank, `-exec rm {} \;` is slower than `-exec rm {} +`, since it runs one each `rm` process per file to delete.

Comment: **Caution**: this will delete `.textClipping` and other types of file that have data in extended attributes alone. See the example in [post 3](https://discourse.trueos.org/t/trying-to-delete-0-byte-files/596/3?u=grahamperrin) under **Trying to delete 0 byte files - The Lounge - TrueOS Community**

Comment: @GrahamPerrin, indeed -- a worthwhile notice for folks using **any** answer presently available on this question. Might you consider adding your own which avoids deleting files with nonempty xattrs?

Comment: I'll try; it'll require help from someone with better knowledge, than me, on composing commands. I have someone in mind. Also please note that I am not testing pre-release APFS, so I can not tell whether utilities such as `find` and `ls` will behave, with APFS, as they do with HFS Plus with regard to not counting data in extended attributes and/or resource forks.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin, ...I'd expect them to comply with POSIX, and inasmuch as POSIX xattrs' size aren't counted in the file size returned by `stat()`, I would expect the tools to continue to reflect that so long as the standard requires them to.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin, (by the way, if you *can* extract information about xattrs from `find`, I'd strongly suggest doing so: The output from `ls` [can't be relied on for programmatic use](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); some of the output at the *beginning* of each line is well-specified, but that doesn't extend through the timestamp, much less the name).

Comment: Anyhow -- once you have a proposal, feel free to @-notice me in for critique (and, hopefully, suggestions around robustness improvements). This is one of those cases where we want to be really careful around the corners -- if someone could get you to delete `/etc/passwd` via `d=$'/tmp/ \n/etc/passwd\n/' mkdir -p -- "$d" && touch "$d/empty.txt"` -- a class of fault many scripts relying on newlines to delimit filenames share -- that would be a comparably unfortunate bug.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy in which of these rooms would you like to chat: [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat), [Ask Different Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) or [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)? I suggest the former, as I might rope in someone else with knowledge of FreeBSD-based systems.

Answer (score 9):

You can lower the potentially huge number of forks to run /bin/rm by:

```
find . -type f -size 0 -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f
```

The above command is very portable, running on most versions of Unix rather than just Linux boxes, and on versions of Unix going back for decades.  For long file lists, several `/bin/rm` commands may be executed to keep the list from overrunning the command line length limit.

A similar effect can be achieved with less typing on more recent OSes, using a `+` in `find` to replace the most common use of `xargs` in a style still lends itself to other actions besides `/bin/rm`.  In this case, `find` will handle splitting truly long file lists into separate `/bin/rm` commands.  The `{}` is customarily quoted to keep the shell from doing anything to it; the quotes aren't always required but the intricacies of shell quoting are too involved to cover here, so when in doubt, include the apostrophes:

```
find . -type f -size 0 -exec /bin/rm -f '{}' +
```

In Linux, briefer approaches are usually available using `-delete`. Note that recent `find`'s `-delete` primary is directly implemented with `unlink`(2) and doesn't spawn a zillion `/bin/rm` commands, or even the few that `xargs` and `+` do.  Mac OS `find` also has the `-delete` and `-empty` primaries.

```
find . -type f -empty -delete
```

To stomp empty (and newly-emptied) files - directories as well - many modern Linux hosts can use this efficient approach:

```
find . -empty -delete
```

Comment: This _does_ improve portability, granted -- but `find -exec ... {} +` is available beyond only Linux. Immediately offhand, both Solaris 11 and OS X support this recent addition to the POSIX specification for find (added in issue 6 of 1003.1).

Comment: The '+' syntax is less portable, but still pretty portable.  It's definitely not available on a number of *old* Unixen that *do* have `xargs`.  `xargs` is also much more flexible than the `+`, although the frequency of needing that extra flex is really low.  I'll add the `+` form, though.

Comment: @AlexNorth-Keys, ...but do those old-UNIX systems have `xargs -0`, or `find -print0`? If not, you have safety/correctness issues trying to do without.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Unix 7th and 8th editions apparently didn't have -print0 (or xargs, for that matter).  In 1988, SunOS didn't have -print0 either, but *does* have xargs. So you're correct that *old* Unix systems aren't going to have them.  IRIS 6.5's find(1) from 1998, no -print0.  However, GNU find added -print0 in November 1990, so "decades" is still accurate, providing the GNU version of find was compiled locally.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path/to/stuff -empty
```

If that's the list of files you're looking for then make the command:

```
find /path/to/stuff -empty -exec rm {} \;
```

Be careful! There won't be any way to undo this!

Comment: Better to use + than ; if you have a current find -- that way it acts the way xargs would if it were in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
find . -type f -size 0b -exec rm {} ';'
```

with all the other possible variations to limit what gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution in case you want to do it inside ONE particular folder:

1. Go inside the folder, right click -> view -> as list.
2. Now you'll find all the files listed as a list. Click on "Size" which must be a column heading. This will sort all the files based on it's size.
3. Finally, you can find all the files that have zero bites at the last. Just select those and delete it!